# groovy : how to modfiy value in closure ( similar with shell pipe )

Tags: groovy, closures

to simplify the code, I tried to using pipe-similar usage like below:

- `foo( 'abc' )` -> `'abc ~> 123'` ( default result )
- `foo( 'abc' ).bar( 'efg' )` -> `'efg : abc ~> 123'` ( additional if necessary )

So, I tried to using **Map** + **Closure** to handle as below:

```
def foo ( String aStr ) {
    String constant = '123'
    String result = "${aStr} ~> ${constant}"

    [
        bar : { String bStr -> result = "${bStr} : ${result}"; return result }
    ]
    println result
}

foo( 'abc' )                    // abc ~> 123
foo( 'abc' ).bar( 'efg' )       // java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method bar() on null object
```

---

### second try

I was added **default** key in Map structure as below. It works well, however :

- call `println` twice
- additional `default` key-value has to be added

```
def foo ( String aStr ) {
    String constant = '123'
    String result = "${aStr} ~> ${constant}"
    
    [
        bar     : { String bStr -> result = "${bStr} : ${result}"; println "${result}" } ,
        default : { println result }
    ]
}

foo( 'abc' ).bar( 'efg' )          // efg : abc ~> 123
foo( 'abc' ).default()             // abc ~> 123
```

---

### third try

make `bar` allows non-parameter, so it can be call as `foo(..).bar()`, but stills cannot be invoking via `foo(..)` directly

```
def foo ( String aStr ) {
    String constant = '123'
    String result = "${aStr} ~> ${constant}"

    [
        bar : { String bStr = '' -> result = "${bStr ? "${bStr} : " : ''}${result}"; return result }
    ]
}

foo( 'abc' )                 // [bar:ConsoleScript22$_foo_closure1@5e7667fd]
foo( 'abc' ).bar()           // abc ~> 123
foo( 'abc' ).bar( 'efg' )    // efg : abc ~> 123
```

is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I grasp the question, but you could write a helper class which generates a chain of elements

```
class Result {
    String name
    def value

    def bar(String aStr) {
        new Result(name: aStr, value: this)
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return "${name} ~> ${value}"
        } else {
            return "${name} : ${value?.toString()}"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your Foo method becomes:

```
Result foo(String aStr) {
    new Result(name: aStr, value: '123')
}
```

And calling the following, prints the following results:

```
println foo('abc')
println foo('abc').bar('efg')
println foo('abc').bar('efg').bar('hahaha')
```

```
abc ~> 123
efg : abc ~> 123
hahaha : efg : abc ~> 123
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! Using `Class` indeed a good solution !